# Strange ODE separation of variables problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an exercise which is obviously wrong and I am trying to figure out what the author meant to say:

> Given $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continous, show that the solution $\varphi(t)$ of $$ \dot{x} = f(t)x, \quad x(0) = 1 $$ exists for all $ t \in \mathbb{R}$ iff $$ \int_0^t f(s) \, ds < 1 \quad (t \in \mathbb{R}) $$

Set $f \equiv 1$ for a counterexample. What could the integral condition possible be good for?

Comment: Your counterexample is not a counterexample; the solution of $x^\prime = x$ and $x(0)=1$ is $x(t)=e^t$.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with $x(t)=e^t$?

Comment: Perhaps the integral condition has to do with uniform boundedness of the solution?

Comment: @par $e^t$ exists for all $t$, but $f \equiv 1$ does **not** satisfy the integral condition, i.e. counterexample

Comment: Ah, I see, "iff", not "if".

Answer (score 0):

This is merely some calculations supporting your statement. Where did you find this exercise?

The differential equation is separable, and
$$
\int_{0}^t \frac{x'}{x}\,dt = \int_0^t f(s)\,ds.
$$
The right-hand side is the integral you look at. The left-hand side is
$$
\log(x(t))-\log(x(0))=\log(x(t)).
$$
Thus, the general solution would be
$$
x(t)=\exp\Bigl(\int_0^t f(s)\,ds\Bigr).
$$
I don't see why the integral must be less than one in order for $x$ to exist for all real $t$. Either they meant to ask for something differently, or something is wrong with the condition.

Comment: Probably the author meant to say that the integral is finite for all $t$, not less than $1$.

Comment: @JackLee the integral always is finite, since $f$ is continuous

Comment: @amey: Oh, right. What was I thinking? More to the point, I wonder what the person who wrote the exercise was thinking?